# how to insert data into <span class="error"> </span>

Tags: javascript

here is my code:

```
<form action="eventssearch.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkDate();">
    <p>
        <label for="date1">Date in the format DD/MM/YYYY:</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date11" />
        <input type="submit" value="Check " />
        <br />(example 26/04/1975) <span class="error"> </span>
    </p>
</form>
```

I wrote the following code which didnt work:

```
var dateField=document.getElementById('error');
dateField.value = "hi Mom"
```

Is there some kind of parent-child relationship here which I am not seeing ? If so, how can I spot it ?

Comment: You have no element with `#id` like `error` in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue, you are calling the function `getElementById('error')`, when the span element has a class 'error', not an id. Hence it will never find it. You should change the `class="error"` to `id="error"`. Then you can say `dateFiled.innerHtml = "Hi Mom"` instead of `.value`

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="error"></span>

<script>
    var dateField = document.getElementsByClassName('error');
    dateField[0].innerHTML = 'hi Mom';

    //or you could use
    var dateField2 = document.getElementByClassName('error');
    dateField2[0].textContent = 'hi Mom'; // this is using dom nodes
</script>
```

view fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/tFrx7/

Get the element by class name if it is span `class=error`

Comment: thank you, but you didnt answer my second question: Is there some kind of parent-child relationship here which I am not seeing

Comment: if you want to use nodes to traverse the DOM, there is a different way

Comment: The question used `.getElementById('error');`. There's no logical reason to use a class here, instead. Fix the HTML, instead of modifying the code to work with incorrect HTML ;-)

Comment: the title says '<span class="error">'

Comment: Sometimes, there is an better way to do what the OP wants to do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use right method to get class instance but you are using `getElementById()` for getting class instance. Use `getElementsByClassName()` or `querySelector()` method and second, I think you should use `innerHTML` if you are using javascript or if you are using jquery then use `text()` or `html()` method.

Solution:

```
var err = document.getElementsByClassName('error')[0];
err.innerHTML = "say hi!";
```